# friendly url with letters not working wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I've got a wordpress page... I was trying to make some URLs friendly but if URL has letters it redirects me to home(404)

My `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteRule ^pieza/([a-z0-9\-]+)/?$ pieza/?refid=$1
```

if I access to mysite.com/pieza/21414 is all good but if I add any letter it redirects me to home(404 I guess)...

> Example: mysite.com/pieza/21414test or mysite.com/pieza/21414-hello

I've tried so many things but it didn't work ...

I think it is because wordpress rewrite rule api or something like that but can't figure out how to disable it on that page... I also tried adding a rewrite rule with wordpress but didn't work.

Comment: Is pieza page slug?

Comment: yes. Pieza is a page slug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Could make it this way:

```
function my_insert_rewrite_rules( $rules )
    {
        $newrules = array();
        $newrules['(pieza)/([^/]*)$'] = 'index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&refid=$matches[2]';
        return $newrules + $rules;
    }
    function my_insert_query_vars( $vars )
    {
        array_push($vars, 'refid');
         return $vars;
    }
    add_filter( 'query_vars','my_insert_query_vars' );
    add_filter( 'rewrite_rules_array','my_insert_rewrite_rules' );
```

Comment: solved. I had to add in the permalinks this structure /%postname%/%friendly%

And it's working fine right now... Thanks for your help