# Convert Wordpress url with querystring to slash-delimited "friendly" url

Tags: php, wordpress, url-rewriting, query-string, friendly-url

I want this link: site.com/c/web/theme/?filter_cms=wp

Convert to: site.com/c/web/theme/wp/

I found this code and edited it a bit:

```
add_action('init', function () {
     add_rewrite_rule('^c/web/theme/([a-z]+)/?$', 'index.php?product_cat=theme&filter_cms=$matches[1]', 'top');
});
```

it displays the desired category(theme) perfectly, but it does not display our filter query: ?filter_cms=wp! What is the problem?

c = WooCommerce category prefix

web = WC category

theme = WC sub-category

cms=wp = WooCommerce attribute

Comment: Stack Overflow has a lot of content on this topic.  Did you find any relevant pages while researching? Where did you find that snippet in your question?

Comment: Is this relevant/helpful? [friendly url with letters not working wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45076791/2943403)  I don't know what you've already read.  Do you need to do something with `tags` and `rules`? [Wordpress add parameters with friendly url structure](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74175051/2943403)